# Translating programming language terms: Talking about python libraries should I really translate them as "Bibliotheken"?

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, anglicism

Using my searchengine, I can find several pages that refer to "Python libraries" as "Python-Bibliotheken".

I am however afraid that my hits are just auto-translated homepages. Can anyone who works in/with programming confirm which is the correct and most common use? Would my German Speaking colleague write a tutorial that says "lade die Bibliothek" or "lade die Library".

I know from experience that for Biotech (Sequencing) my German speaking colleagues did refer to "Library prep" with the anglicism, in their in-house manuals.

Comment: To be an engineer in Germany you have to have good English. Many textbooks are in English anyway. Your customers will understand most technical terms, in fact seeing the German word in an unexpected context might puzzle them. Also, in e.g. space and defence, projects may well be conducted in English and not all personnel will be German.

Comment: "Python Bibliotheken" is wrong. Correct would be "Python-Bibliotheken".

Comment: The answer may depend on whether you write about python libraries or Python libraries.

Comment: In general, I've found Wikipedia's "Languages" tab useful for finding corresponding technical terms. For example, the enwiki article "Library (computing)" links to the dewiki article "Programmbibliothek". Of course, this only works for topics notable enough to have their own Wikipedia articles.

Comment: @xehpuk ty. Could you provide a better source than this: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Wann-muss-der-Bindestrich-gebraucht-werden I mean I know "Universitätsbibliothek" is written in one word - so why not "Pythonbibliothek" (no hits in the duckduck.go). I would guess its mostly convention. Also: In all of the 3 search engines I use (ddg/qwant/google) I find both "Python Bibliotheken" & "Python-Bibliotheken" Eg "Python Bibliotheken" from https://lerneprogrammieren.de/python-bibliotheken/  "Python Standardbibliothek" https://www.python-lernen.de/python-standardbibliothek.htm

Comment: @ilamengl I'm not saying "Pythonbibliothek" is wrong (but indeed unusual), I'm just saying "Python Bibliothek" is definitely wrong. You can't trust random native speakers to write correctly. This is a typical case of [Deppenleerzeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deppenleerzeichen). Official sources would be [§ 37](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6155) and [§ 51](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6160).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"Library" is a very old word in software technology, it goes back to 1947 and John von Neumann if the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) is to be believed. So people had *a lot* of time getting used to it (and its ridiculousness if you think of files of some KBytes size on early computers). The same is true for the translations in other languages, that are almost as old and have also been used way before English terms became the *ubiquitous language* of software development.

> German: Bibliothek
> French: bibliothèque
> Spanish: biblioteca / librería
> Italian: libreria
> ... *(follow the Wikipedia language links to see it)*

So yes, you can absolutely use it. It doesn't sound any more strange to a German developer than "library" does in English. You can use the English word if you want, but with a word as basic as this to software, there's no really good reason to do that.

It's different for many more modern or more technical concepts though. Nobody calls a *promise* "Versprechen", or *responsive design* "empfängliche Gestaltung". We often just go with the English terms or with English loan words like "responsives Design" ("responsiv" wasn't used in German before, certainly not in the same sense). This way, we avoid misunderstandings due to divergent translations. "Bibliothek" predates that notion.

Comment: "It's different for more modern concepts though." - it's actually not limited to modern concepts. IMHO, using terms like "Halde" for "heap" or "Kellerspeicher" for "stack" makes you sound quite antiquated. "Bibliothek" is in a different category, it sounds completely idiomatic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I agree, there are earlier more technical words that never got a widely used German equivalent. I would definitely use *stack* and *heap*. I have never heard of "Halde" or "Kellerspeicher" in software development, I know "Stapelspeicher" but would probably not use it. I just looked in my (very bad) German 1983 edition of K&R "The C programming language", and they use "Stack" and "Standard Bücherei (sic)".

Comment: @HalvarF, omg, it may actually have been that bad K&R translation where I first encountered German compound nouns with spaces. I was so confused, I at first did not even understand what that was supposed to mean.

Comment: @HalvarF: interestingly, the concept of a stack was in fact first published by two Germans, Klaus Samelson and Friedrich L. Bauer, using the term "Keller".

Comment: When I first came to Germany in the 80s, I was alarmed to read docu from a well established German electronics firm. I had to ask "what is a Stapelzeiger?" Everyone laughed, because that is an extreme example of over-translating. Everyone else would write Stackpointer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Walter Tichy would like to talk to you. Context; He translates everything into german: Thread <=> Ausführungsfaden for example

Comment: @o.m. but in the case of uploads, I definitely don't see why anyone bothers with this weirdness, instead of using the perfectly good “hochgeladen”.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt thanks for posting that, I had no idea! Very interesting indeed,

Comment: That's the literal translation I suppose, in Spain, we (technicians/developers) say "Libreria(s)", not Biblioteca(s).
But I lived in Germany too (working in other branch), and I think there's no word for a 1:1 translation

Comment: I see your Halde and raise you my Serielle Mauszeigereinheit.

Comment: In the old days, I have seen people try to have Mutterbretter and Zwischenbruch-Prozessierung. Seriously.

Answer (score 9):

In German texts on programming you can use both, the anglicism 'Library' is used frequently and understood in the programming community; however the proper German word is indeed 'die Bibliothek / die Bibliotheken', and is also commonly used.

<s>However when talking about Python, IMHO the word 'library' is not used very often - also not in English. Often one speaks of packages (de 'das Paket / die Pakete) as a bigger collection of stuff and modules (de: das Modul / die Module) with a more limited scope; the other terms are less well-defined when talking about python code (e.g. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198166/whats-the-difference-between-a-module-and-a-library-in-python</s>

Comment: I feel your remarks about the word "library" in python context is wrong. I use python in my job all day and we do call our libraries libraries :) True, any library is also a package and also a module. But when you refer to code as to a "library", this implies a certain perspective on the code - this is code that is foreign to your application, an external dependency.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach When the job ad calls for it: In a German CV would you list them under the bullet point "libraries: x,y,z" or "Bibliotheken: x,yz"?

Comment: @ilamengl Whenever I applied for a python job, I wrote my application in English :) In a German CV, I would write _Bibliotheken_

Answer (score 3):

When (and if) to translate special terms of a certain trade - and, in general, when and if to use foreign words at all - is a very broad and ongoing discussion and i want to warn you up front that i can describe this topic only from my point of view - which is not neutral at all because i have an opinion myself about this.

But, first off, let us clarify: the discussion which takes place in IT is NOT about *foreign words*, it is solely about *english words*. The people insisting on the use of "Bibliothek" - which is greek ("η βιβλιοθήκη") - instead of "Library" (which is english of latin origin) won't use the real german "Bücherei" instead of "Bibliothek" at all.

### Why to Translate Everything

Many times foreign words are not used because they have added meaning but because using them is somehow perceived "cool". I remember sitting in the ICE and overhearing a guy talking on the phone:

> ... und nach dem Breakfast Meeting da haben wir die Local Markets gepollt und diesen Input dann in den Spread Sheets processed...

Quite honestly: i heard that and asked myself what he tries to cover. This is a sort of language where one can't tell any truth and lying is the default.

But then, using words out of context because they are perceived as "cool" does not only happen to foreign terms. I live in a social cesspool and often hear "krass" and "konkret" being used like:

> Weiß'du, Alda, hab isch krasse neue BMW, hat konkret zweihundatfuffsich PS, i schwör!

(In case you are wondering if i overdid it: this very sentence i heard about a week ago while waiting in a Kebab restaurant.)

### Why Not to Translate At All

Every trade develops its own specific vocabulary. Often words are not used with the same meaning they have in everyday speech. These different meanings are often quite (narrowly) well-defined and translating them would take away from their special meaning. German physicians talk about a "Luxation" rather than a "Umrichtung" and a "Fraktur" rather than a "Bruch". The reason is that "Fraktur" and "Luxation" have very precise definitions every physiscian is aware of whereas "Bruch" and "Umrichtung" don't.

The same is true for IT and its - because of historical reasons english - *termini technici*. For instance, the usual translation of "device" is "Gerät" - because the german doorstopper magazine *Computerbild* created that "translation" and later Microsoft adopted it for their toy OS. But if you take a look into a dictionary (for instance: [here](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/device)) you will find for "device":

> das Gerät
> das Mittel
> der Kunstgriff

...and so on. I once wrote an article in the german Wikipedia about */dev/null* and called it a "device". The discussion went like this:

> .../dev/null ist ein Device ....
> Nein! Das heißt "Gerät"!
> Aber es ja gar kein Gerät!
> Na, wenn es kein Gerät ist, dann ist es ein *virtuelles Gerät*!

The reason is that creating an entry in the /dev tree and having methods of accessing the device like a file is indeed a "device" but the translation for such a feat of artistic brilliancy would rather be "Kunstgriff".

### What to Do and When to Do it.

The austrian poet Karl Kraus - often attacked for his use of foreign words - once put it like this (i am paraphrasing here):

> Man soll nicht von Kretins sprechen, wenn man es mit Trotteln zu tun hat [...] andererseits hat auch ein Fremdwort seinen Reiz und speziell die Farbe der Stupidität wird weder von der Einfalt noch der Dummheit vollgültig ersetzt.
> <sub>One shouldn't call them cretins when dealing with putzes but on the other hand stupidity cannot be replaced in every nuance by neither the simple-mindedness nor the oafishness</sub>.

What he polemically suggests here is actually sound advice: don't bother to use foreign words if they do not add meaning to your language. Don't be shy to use them, though, if they do.

For your case of "library" in an IT-context that means: "library" is part of the the IT jargon and denominates a certain *device*. Its meaning is well established within IT folk. For the suggestion to use "Bibliothek" as translation: see above. You would just replace an english term with a greek term and the german "Bücherei" would not be understood in this context at all.

Comment: "Bibliothek" has been used in the German language since the early 16th century according to DWDS. I strongly disagree with the statement that "library" is more part of German IT jargon than "Bibliothek", the opposite is true. A library is also not a device, by any stretch.

Comment: A library is a device for organizing precompiled functions - without any stretch. In fact i was playing with the meaning "Kunstgriff" i introduced above.

Comment: In IT jargon, both "device" and "library" are terms with an established meaning. Of course you can use "device" in a broader sense, ("a rhyme is a device of poetry") but that's very  misleading here, especially when saying "a library is a certain device".

Comment: emphasized "device" to make clear its meaning

Comment: While your answer is an interesting read and could do as an essay, yet I think it misses the question and (or even because) it is wrong on the presumption that "Bibliothek" is an uncommon and foreign-perceived word to the German language - the opposite is true.

Comment: @planetmaker: i have not said that "Bibliothek" is wrong or uncommon, i have argued that "avoid library because it is a foreign word" is nonsense because "Bibliothek" is also a foreign word. This whole discussion about foreign words in IT is NOT about foreign words but about *english foreign words* alone. Words of greek or latin origin ("System" isntead of "Anordnung") are accepted at face value.

Comment: Exactly. But "Bibliothek" is not a foreign word. That's where the argument fails: the premise is already not true (anymore). We don't live in the 16th century anymore. The argument more generally is to introduce (new) foreign words because they add to understanding, or use an existing word (and possibly broaden or change its meaning in a particular context). The main consideration should always be: choose the word which serves best, both your audience's understanding and your purpose.

Comment: @Obviously we have different definitions for what a "foreign word" is. The german word for "Bibliothek" is "Bücherei" and - as i have explained above in detail - "Bibliothek" is greek (from "biblios", the book). "Library" is used in german for several decades now, "Bibliothek" for some centuries. At which point exactly does a word of foreign origin become a not any more foreign word, then, by your definition? (an exact number of years would be appreciated)

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=dta%2Bdwds&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1600%3A1999&q1=bibliothek&q2=b%C3%BCcherei zeigt eindeutig, dass "Bibliothek" das um mehrfach gebräuchlichere Wort ist - seit Jahrhunderten. Hinzu kommt, dass Schreibung und Aussprache dem typisch Deutschen entsprechen. Das kann man von Library noch lange nicht sagen. Von Majonäse vs. Mayonnaise kann man demzufolge zu Recht behaupten, dass es in den letzen Jahrzehnten sich vom Fremdwort zum eingedeutschten Wort entwickelt hat.

Comment: Insofern helfen im eigentlichen Sinne Jahreszahlen oder Zeiträume nicht weiter, sondern der Gebrauch, in Hinsicht auf Schreibung als auch Grammatik. Insofern ist nicht ersichtlich, warum man "Bibliothek" den Status eines Fremdwortes zuweisen will und kann. Dass es Ursprung im Griechischen hat, tut dabei wenig zur Sache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136786/discussion-between-planetmaker-and-bakunin).

Comment: @bakunin Not arguing for the usage of "Gerät" in instead of device, but afaik device does in that context actually mean "Gerät". Like the /dev/ path is meant for devices (Geräte), both the physical and the virtual ones. So to use /dev/null as the idomatic "scream into the void" thing is certainly a "Kunstgriff", but afaik what you're actually doing is that you pass your unwanted output of a program as input to a non-existing device not a virtual. That way that information is "out of your system" because the device is supposed to handle it, but as there is no device, it's just gone for good.

Comment: The /dev path is indeed meant for "devices" but these devices are NOT "Geräte". Which "Gerät" is /dev/random? Which Gerät is /dev/mapper/* in Linux? Or the VGs in AIX and Linux, which all have an entry in /dev? And if you base your argument on hdisks: which one is the "Gerät", the block-oriented or the character-oriented entry? I could go on. Just have a look in your "Berechner" and see what is stored on the "Hartscheibe".

Comment: @bakunin I get It you don't like forceful translations of established technical terms for the sake of it. Neither do I. But often times the words that end up as technical Jargon in German are in English just everyday words describing a simple functionality or feature. And I'd argue there is value in being aware of that. What is better to wave your hands and argue "Yeah a device is that complex thing that can be this and that and that ..." or to be able to say "A device is a machine and /dev/ is concerned with handling machines." And btw your examples are still concerned with Geräte...

Comment: @haxor789: OK, technical jargon consists of everyday words in english. So? "Technical jargon" in medicine also comes from everyday latin (or greek) words. "Fraktur" is from "fractus" - broken. Still, physicians still say "Fraktur" and not "Brechung" or "Bruch". Why is nobody calling them out for saying "Appendektomie" instead of "Anhangsherauschneidung"? Because the words they use are not *english* words but latin ones. So, either we admit that english jargon is bad but all other jargon is OK - quite hypocritical IMHO - or we stop translating jargon at all.

Comment: @haxor789: Furthermore, i wonder which "Gerät" a volume group should be....

Comment: @bakunin That's totally OT but it's actually debatable whether jargon adds rigor, brevity and simplifies communication or whether it's a version of "Herrschaftssprache", that is intended to confuse and obfuscate, in order to maintain an expert status. And ironically medicine is an prime example for where that's really relevant. And it's probably easier for a native English speaker to read and comprehend a manual encountering everyday language than for a German speaker who has to memorize and conceptualize unfamiliar terms. It's not about a hate for the English language...

Comment: @bakunin ... not to mention that tons of English terms are of Latin/French or even Germanic origin to begin with... And also English jargon is great. Means you've got a massive user base and a lot more resources. That being said it's not always bad to know what these words mean in everyday English and not just use them as technical terms, because they are often named like that for a reason. Also VGs map internal information handling to external information handling (such as required by devices).

Comment: @haxor789: of course we could do great without jargon. Lets just talk about the thingie with the you-know-what at the end - you know, the green one..... Ludwig Wittgenstein comes to mind: "Die Grenzen meiner Sprache sind die Grenzen meiner Welt." I prefer my world without walls and borders (so that i can do away with windows and gates).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137211/discussion-between-haxor789-and-bakunin).